# tinyint is shown as checkbox on gridview?

Tags: c#, gridview

I have a several data column from my MySQL database, the type is tinyint(1)

my code in form

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
dt = PC.getValue(textBox.Text);
dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
dataGridView1.AutoResizeColumns();
```

and MyQuery

```
public DataTable getValue(string yearmonth)
{
    connSIMRS.Open();
    MySqlCommand command = new MySqlCommand();
    string sql = "select * from table1 where yearmonth= '"+yearmonth+"'";

    command.CommandText = sql;
    command.Connection = connSIMRS;
    //command.EndExecuteNonQuery();
    MySqlDataAdapter da = new MySqlDataAdapter(command);
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    da.Fill(dt);
    //MessageBox.Show("");
    connSIMRS.Close();
    return dt;
}
```

can't post a picture but it turn into a checkbox. Could it be turn into a boolean? How can I show it as a string?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is being turned into a boolean.  Many ways to turn it into a string.  Use a custom format, custom column, cast it from the database, etc.

Force MySql Connector to do it:
According to the [MySQL Connector Docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-net/en/connector-net-connection-options.html) , just add `TreatTinyAsBoolean=false` to your connection string.

However, I would just use a custom column in the GridView, as most cases I would want the booleans to be displayed as a checkbox, and this allows finer control over which ones I want displayed as text vs checkbox.

Add the obligitory `string sql = "select * from table1 where yearmonth= '"+yearmonth+"'";` is bad.  Don't do that EVER.